# Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE for plugin creation throws errors all over

Tags: c++, c++11, plugins, qt5

Environment:

- Framework: Qt 5.12.9
- Compiler: MSVC 15.9.28307.1234 (x64)
- Debugger: CDB 10.017763.132 (x64)
- Standard: C++11
- Editor: Qt Creator 4.12.2
- OS: Win10 Enterprise 1809

I want to develop an application that can be expanded through plug-ins. Therefore I created a standard library project where I want to define the plug-in interfaces. This library should then be consumed by the main application and its plug-ins.

I read about the Qt plug-in system on the official websites and sought help by duckduckgo-ing, but I'm stuck with these following errors:

- vccplugin.h:16:32: error: expected parameter declarator
  vccplugin.h:14:23: note: expanded from macro 'VccPlugin_iid'
- vccplugin.h:16:32: error: expected ')'
  vccplugin.h:14:23: note: expanded from macro 'VccPlugin_iid'
  vccplugin.h:16:20: note: to match this '('
- vccplugin.h:16:1: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
- Build Issue: C2059: syntax error: 'string'

This is the code:

```
#ifndef VCCPLUGIN_H
#define VCCPLUGIN_H

#include "VccPluginInterface_global.h"

class VCCPLUGININTERFACE_EXPORT VccPlugin
{
public:
    VccPlugin();
    ~VccPlugin();
    void DoeEenTwuk();
};

#define VccPlugin_iid "automation.general.vcc.interface"

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(VccPlugin, VccPlugin_iid);

#endif // VCCPLUGIN_H
```

Also note, I have little experience in both C++ and Qt.

Any help very appreciated,
thanks

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem by copy-pasting your code to an empty project, before MainWindow declaration, but I don't see it. I am using Qt 5.12.8 MinGW 7.3 32-bit.

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen could it be something with the msvc compiler? I didn't wanted to install mingw since it seems such a hassle and I already had visual studio...

Comment: Can you try to do the same, creating a minimal example. See if the problem is still there. Something like this https://pastebin.com/bKqkspgK.

Comment: Weird, with your example using my same kit, I don't have the error anymore. Should there be something wrong with my project file? See https://pastebin.com/idMH5YTH

Comment: I don't see a problem. Since your project is small enough, I suggest commenting out suspicious parts one by one, until you can identify which part of the code is the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. The problem is that the compiler couldn't find the macro, so all I had to add was:

```
#include <QtPlugin>
```

Since Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE is defined in QtPlugin. Your example didn't import QtPlugin but was probably imported implicit by another import, probably QMainWindow.

It would have been simpler if I got an error like: "Could not find symbol Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE" if you ask me. Especially since I'm rather blue in this topic.

Thanks for your support @NgocMinhNguyen and others